# at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, picasso

When i am running application in android then these problems is coming , my error is as follow i am copying here ,

> 07-17 11:46:49.780    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
>   07-17 11:46:49.780    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
>   07-17 11:46:49.784    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:379)
>   07-17 11:46:49.784    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   com.squareup.picasso.ResourceRequestHandler.decodeResource(ResourceRequestHandler.java:54)
>   07-17 11:46:49.784    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   com.squareup.picasso.ResourceRequestHandler.load(ResourceRequestHandler.java:45)
>   07-17 11:46:49.792    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206) 07-17
>   11:46:49.792    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159) 07-17
>   11:46:50.152    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
>   07-17 11:46:50.152    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 07-17
>   11:46:50.152    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   07-17 11:46:50.152    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   07-17 11:46:50.152    1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 07-17 11:46:50.152
>   1507-1532/com.shubham.MeraIndore I/dalvikvm﹕ at
>   com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)

Comment: This appears to be just the stack trace. What is the actual error reported?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so i am explaining you what these all about ,

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.graphics.BitmapFactory
```

Creates Bitmap objects from various sources, including files, streams, and byte-arrays. 
you are getting error because of limited memory , ideally you only want to load a lower resolution version in memory. The lower resolution version should match the size of the UI component that displays it. An image with a higher resolution does not provide any visible benefit, but still takes up precious memory and incurs additional performance overhead due to additional on the fly scaling.
Although it will not causes any run time error in app .for more details you can visit  https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html